# How editing my own data in gtk_text_editor

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, editor

I have my own data similar text code.
How modyfy a gtk_text_buffer function (and witch?) to read write it into my own data.

For example:

```
char *lines[]={"start","text"....
int numbers[]={1,7,98, numbers coresponding above lines
```

in editor appears

```
color [number in text] : black line
.....
```

i can create a function that simulating get text buffer in utf8. But where i can modyfy function.

I have my own data, not only text. How edit my data using text editor?

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you provide a more concrete example of what you want to do?

Comment: How modyfing a function to using my own buffer not gtk buffer

Comment: or wich function in gtk_text_buffer

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Please explain in detail what you want to accomplish and why the functions in GtkTextBuffer are not good enough.

Comment: My question is clear, I wrote example.  Imagine. For example I need editor for utf32, but I need buffer online, not convert whole. I need utf32 in other window and in texteditor in this same time.